# Laravel observer not triggered

Tags: php, laravel, queue, observers

I register an `observer` in the boot method of `AppServiceProvider`.

Then I listen with `Queue::after` when a certain job has been finished.

The problem is that when I create the `ProjectUserAssignments` in the foreach loop the observer is not triggered! But they are correctly made within the database.

It looks like this:

```
ProjectUserAssignment::observe(ProjectUserAssignmentObserver::class);

Queue::after(function(JobProcessed $event) {
    //When a project is created, create the employees and send to harvest.
    if($event->job->resolveName() == HarvestProjectCreate::class) {
        \Log::debug('start!');
        $project = Project::latest()->first();

        foreach($project->team->employees as $employee) {
            ProjectUserAssignment::create([
                'project_id' => $project->id,
                'user_id'    => $employee->id,
                'is_project_manager' => false
            ]);
        }
    }
});
```

When I individually make 1 `ProjectUserAssignment` the observer is triggered! What could be going on here?

Comment: Does it actually Log 'start!'  also can you put a Log::debug in the foreach loop to make sure it is hitting that as well?

Comment: I'd like to bump this question. I have a model being created on a form submit which DOES trigger the observer:created method. HOWEVER, when I create the same model through a job instead, it DOES NOT trigger. Is this a known bug? Or is there a known work-around?

Comment: I have the same problem too. I'm moving the whole observer into the job to avoid this. I believe there is a bug. At the same time I think the method create does not trigger observer because of bulk operation

Answer (score 3):

Its mention in the Laravel Document that mass assignment method like create will not trigger events like observer.

You have to change to normal insert like

```
$p = new ProjectUserAssignment;
$p->project_id = $project->id;
$p->user_id = $employee->id;
$p->is_project_manager = false;
$p->save();
unset($p) // do this when done in loop to avoid memory shortage
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with an observer triggering on `created` as well and still not too firm with Laravel.
I cannot provide a true answer what the problem is, but hints on where to debug.

Add `dd()` or `Log::info()` calls to see if methods from your app are actually triggered.
This is not limited to your code base. Sometimes you need to look at the internals.

### HasEvents

Location: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents`

- `HasEvents::observe()` - The `$classes` parameter should have yours listed as well.
- `HasEvents::registerObserver()` - Debug the foreach to see if some event doesn't actually exist.
- `HasEvents::fireModelEvent()` - This is called from the base `Model` of Laravel when a model event happens (such as created, updated, etc.). Your observer should be called from here if everything is correct.
- `HasEvents::withoutEvents()` - Be aware that automatic tests may run without model events. `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` does so if trait `WithoutEvents` is used.

### Model

Location: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

- `Model::performInsert()` - Inserting into the database (`'creating'`, `'created'`)
- `Model::performUpdate()` - Updating record in the database (`'updating'`, `'updated'`)
- `Model::delete()` - Deleting record from the database (`'deleting'`, `'deleted'`)
- `fireModelEvent()` calls - Other events are fired here as well, `Ctrl`+`F` your way through if you are interested

### Typo?

If all else fails, check the spelling of files, classes and methods, namespace.

Especially relevant if you have hand-written some classes/methods or copy&pasted code for another Laravel version. Have to mention this, just-in-case.

This is sadly more often than not at the root of the problem.
Everything else might be worth a ticket for the Laravel dev team. Provided you have an example project to test this on.